# Apache Beam Spark Portable Runner

Tags: apache-beam

I am running a sample pipeline and my environment is this.

python "SaiStudy - Apache-Beam-Spark.py" --runner=PortableRunner --job_endpoint=192.168.99.102:8099

My Spark is running on a Docker Container and I can see that the JobService is running at 8099.

I am getting the following error:
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1603539936.536000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_chann
el.cc","file_line":4090,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1603539936.536000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/cli
ent_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}"

When I curl to ip:port, I can see the following error from the docker logs
Oct 24, 2020 11:34:50 AM org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport notifyTerminated
INFO: Transport failed
org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: Unexpected HTTP/1.x request: GET /
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:103)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.readClientPrefaceString(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:302)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:239)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:438)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

Please find instruction here how to setup PortableRunner for Spark:
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/

Basically you need to setup additional Docker container (as described) which acts as runner between Beam (in any language) and Spark.
You connect Beam to runner, and runner to the Spark.